# Why doesn't this prepare statement work in MYSQLI?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I created this code:

```
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM phptech_contact");
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->result_metadata();
$object = $result->fetch_object();

print_r( $object );
```

When I run it, it doesn't work. Can anybody tell me why it doesn't work?

I have 20 rows in this table so data should be returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://ch.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.result-metadata.php

`Note: The result set returned by mysqli_stmt_result_metadata() contains only metadata. It does not contain any row results. The rows are obtained by using the statement handle with mysqli_stmt_fetch().`

As long as you don't need this meta data you don't need to call this method.

```
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT fld1, fld2 FROM phptech_contact");
$statement->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($fld1, $fld2);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "$fld1 and $fld2<br />";
}
```

But I really dislike the mysqli extension. PDO is much cooler ... ;-)

```
$db = new PDO('...');
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT fld1, fld2 FROM phptech_contact");
$stmt->execute();

while ($obj = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
    // ...
}
```

or

```
$objs = stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Comment: shut i make like you "$fld1" and "$fld2" i think if i select * out. :)

Comment: and yes, PDO its much easyere, i ges i hav use PDO before bot i what to try mysqli bot now i can se i maby not wanna go to MySQLi bot go to PDO. :) tanks a lot for help.

Comment: PDO is the more modern of the two. Nowadays there’s usually no reason to use anything else.

Answer (score 3):

if you're trying to get the rows from the database, the function you need is [`mysqli_stmt::fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php), not `mysqli_stmt::fetch_metadata()`

You're also missing a few steps.  When using prepared statements, you must specify the fields you would like to return instead of using the star wildcard, and then use [`mysqli_stmt::bind_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) to specify which variables the database fields should be placed in.

If you're more familiar with the original MySQL extension, prepared statements have a  different process to use.  If your select statement has a parameter (eg., "WHERE value=?") prepared statements are definitely recommended, but for your simple query, [`mysqli:query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)  would be sufficient, and not very different from the process of `mysql_query()`

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that `mysqli_stmt::result_metadata()` returns a `mysqli_result` object without any of the actual results — it only holds metadata.

So what you want to do is [use `$result = $statement->bind_result(...)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) and then call `$result->fetch()` repeatedly to get the results.

[One of the comments under the bind-result() article shows how to do this for a query like yours](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#85470), where you don't necessarily know all of the columns being returned.